# Does a resolution of a rational singularity have rationally connected fibers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, birational-geometry, singularity-theory

A rational singularity is a singularity of a
complex variety $X$ such that for any
resolution $\pi:\; \tilde X\rightarrow X$ the
higher direct images $R^i\pi_*(O_{\tilde X})$
vanish for all $i>0$. Suppose that $X$
has isolated rational singularity,
and $\tilde X\rightarrow X$ its resolution.
I expect that the fiber of $\pi$ over
the singular point is rationally
connected; I would be very grateful
for any reference to this. I need to apply
this to the local situation, so it would be
especially nice if the argument does not
use projectivity.

Comment: Do you want to assume that the singularities are also Gorenstein?  Then it should follow from Elkik together with Hacon-McKernan's proof of Shokurov's conjecture.

Comment: Many thanks, yes, the examples I meant have crepant resolutions

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. For instance the cone over an Enriques surface (with respect to any projective embedding) has rational singularity, but Enriques surface is not rationally connected.

Comment: Does this also work for the cone over a K3 surface or a surface of general type?

Comment: The rationality of singularity condition is $H^{>0}(S, \oplus_{k \ge 0} L^k) = 0$, where $L$ is the ample line bundle defining the embedding. In particular, $H^{>0}(S,\mathcal{O}_S) = 0$ is necessary, so K3 surface won't work. But some surface of general type, such as fake projective planes, do work.