# Existence of a rational curve in the center of a birational contraction for symplectic singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program, hyperkaehler

Let $M$ be a holomorphically symplectic
complex manifold, and $f: M \to X$
a holomorphic, birational contraction to a Stein
variety $X$, contracting a subvariety $E$
to a point, and bijective outside of $E$.

When $M$ is quasiprojective, it is known that $E$
is Lagrangian with respect to the holomorphic
symplectic form. This fact is proven as follows.
First, we note that $E$ is isotropic with respect
to the holomorphic symplectic form (this is one line
argument). Then,  using some deep results of MMP
(due to Kawamata and Shokurov, I think), one shows
that $E$ contains a rational curve. Then the
dimension of $E$ is bounded from below, using
the deformation theory of this curve.

I want to have this result without $M$
being quasiprojective. I can show that
$E$ is isotropic, and it is Lagrangian
if and only if $E$ contains a rational curve.
However, I don't see how to prove existence
of a rational curve: the MMP arguments are
way too complicated, and don't work in this
context. I would be very grateful for
any pointers which could be used to show
existence of a rational curve on the
exceptional set.

In algebraic context, the existence of rational curves
was discussed there:
[Does a resolution of a rational singularity have rationally connected fibers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404625/does-a-resolution-of-a-rational-singularity-have-rationally-connected-fibers)
and Jason Starr replied that the fiber is
rationally connected, "as follows from
Elkik together with Hacon-McKernan's proof of
Shokurov's conjecture". This is hard,
but existence of a rational curve is
weaker, and I hope it can be proven
without that much effort.

Comment: I was just lecturing about this kind of thing last week in my graduate course (motivated by a seminar speaker who was talking about contractions of irreducible holomorphic symplectic varieties).  I do not know how to prove existence of a rational curve without some quasi-projectivity hypothesis.